# Django + OpenLayers?

Tags: django, openlayers, geodjango

Can anyone point me to a good tutorial on how to use Django or GeoDjango with OpenLayers. I can't seems to find a good tutorial. I'm a beginner in both and haven't used these before. I just need to get a website with maps up and running really fast. So if someone can just tell me how to display a map on a django website I'd be really grateful!!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://docs.openlayers.org/library/introduction.html ?

Comment: OpenLayers do not care if they are working on top of Django or anything else. It's a client side library. So you just load it and put some JS to make it show necessary data. If you need to process geodata on server - take a look at [geodjango](http://geodjango.org/) too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still learning how to work with both, but here's a small overview which might help clarify some things: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034482/rendering-spatial-data-of-geoqueryset-in-a-custom-view-on-geodjango)

You'll want a way to pass data from Django to OpenLayers in a format that OpenLayers can understand. After that, you can use OpenLayers library to manipulate that data.

Here are some examples: http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/