# GeoJSON data doesn't contain meaningful data GeoDjango

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, geojson, geodjango

I'm using `vectorformats` to display GeoDjango data on my map, following [this resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3045721/3156582). I have this in my `views.py` file :

```
def geojsonFeed(request):
    querySet = WorldBorder.objects.filter()
    djf = Django.Django(geodjango="mpoly", properties=['name', 'iso3'])
    geoj = GeoJSON.GeoJSON()
    s = geoj.encode(djf.decode(querySet))
    return HttpResponse(s)
```

But the response looks like this

```
["type", "features", "crs"]
```

Can anyone help me identify what's wrong with my code?

**Update : Added WorldBorder Model**

```
class WorldBorder(models.Model):
    # Regular Django fields corresponding to the attributes in the
    # world borders shapefile.
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    area = models.IntegerField()
    pop2005 = models.IntegerField('Population 2005')
    fips = models.CharField('FIPS Code', max_length=2)
    iso2 = models.CharField('2 Digit ISO', max_length=2)
    iso3 = models.CharField('3 Digit ISO', max_length=3)
    un = models.IntegerField('United Nations Code')
    region = models.IntegerField('Region Code')
    subregion = models.IntegerField('Sub-Region Code')
    lon = models.FloatField()
    lat = models.FloatField()

    # GeoDjango-specific: a geometry field (MultiPolygonField)
    mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField()

    # Returns the string representation of the model.
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I'm using Django 2.1.7

Update 2 :

```
>>> print(querySet)

<QuerySet [<WorldBorder: Antigua and Barbuda>, <WorldBorder: Algeria>, <WorldBorder: Azerbaijan>, <WorldBorder: Albania>, <WorldBorder: Anguilla>, <WorldBorder: Armenia>, <WorldBorder: Angola>, <WorldBorder: American Samoa>, <WorldBorder: Argentina>, <WorldBorder: Australia>, <WorldBorder: Andorra>, <WorldBorder: Gibraltar>, <WorldBorder: Bahrain>, <WorldBorder: Barbados>, <WorldBorder: Bermuda>, <WorldBorder: Bahamas>, <WorldBorder: Bangladesh>, <WorldBorder: Brunei Darussalam>, <WorldBorder: Canada>, <WorldBorder: Cambodia>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use a module (`vectorformats`) that seems to be abandoned and very very old (the PyPi page: https://pypi.org/project/vectorformats/ tells us that this package is from 2009 and stuck in version 0.1)?
What is the Django version you are using for your project?
Also, can you share the `WorldBorder` model in your question?

Comment: Thank you @JohnMoutafis. Though vectorformats is abandoned, I've reused [the poject for recent Python 3 versions](https://github.com/koffisani/vectorformats) and used it in my project as a Git submodule. Kindly look at the updated version of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT After confirmation of non-empty queryset:**

I found the issue and it is related to the core code of the `vectorformats` module.

Specifically, inside `GeoJSON.encode` [on this specific line](https://github.com/koffisani/vectorformats/blob/5faf94ccf84d374a09baf4874a3fb9a4995e8c95/Formats/GeoJSON.py#L55):

```
if to_string:
    result = json_dumps(list(result_data))
```

the **`list()`** is causing the problem.

Let's recreate the issue with a minimal example:

```
>>> import json
>>> test = {'a': 5, 'b': [1, 2, 3], 'c': {'e': 2, 'f': 5}}
>>> list(test)
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Here we see the exact same behavior as the one in the question. Let's take it a bit further:

```
>>> json.dumps(list(test))
'["a", "b", "c"]'
```

But without the `list()`:

```
>>> json.dumps(test)
'{"a": 5, "b": [1, 2, 3], "c": {"e": 2, "f": 5}}'
```

Therefore there are 2 possible solutions around this problem:

1. Change the `vectorformat` code removing the `list()` call.
2. Call the `encode` method with `to_string=False` and "jsonify" the resulting dictionary yourself as follows:

   ```
   import json

   def geojsonFeed(request):
       queryset = WorldBorder.objects.all()
       djf = Django.Django(geodjango="mpoly", properties=['name', 'iso3'])
       geoj = GeoJSON.GeoJSON()
       s = geoj.encode(djf.decode(queryset), to_string=False)
       return HttpResponse(json.dumps(s))
   ```

---

<s>Well from a quick study at your module, it seems to work as intended, so that is not the reason.</s>

Having a look at the [`GeoJSON.encode()`](https://github.com/koffisani/vectorformats/blob/5faf94ccf84d374a09baf4874a3fb9a4995e8c95/Formats/GeoJSON.py#L32) method:

> ```
> def encode(self, features, to_string=True, **kwargs):
>     """
>     Encode a list of features to a JSON object or string.
>     to_string determines whethr it should convert the result to
>     a string or leave it as an object to be encoded later
>     """
>     results = []
>     result_data = None
>     for feature in features:
>         data = self.encode_feature(feature)
>         for key,value in data['properties'].items():
>             if value and isinstance(value, str): 
>                 data['properties'][key] = str(value)
>         results.append(data)
>
>    result_data = {
>                    'type':'FeatureCollection',
>                    'features': results,
>                    'crs': self.crs
>                   }
>
>    if to_string:
>         result = json_dumps(list(result_data))
>    else:
>         result = result_data
>    return result
> ```

The `result_data` has the structure `["type", "features", "crs"]` and it is transformed to a json list because you have the `to_string` argument by default `True`.

The only reason for your problem I can imagine is that the `querySet = WorldBorder.objects.filter()` query is **empty**.

By the way, by using `filter()` with no arguments, you have a similar result to an `all()` query.

Comment: Thank you, @John, for your help.  `print(querySet)` returns this : `print(querySet)
<QuerySet [<WorldBorder: Antigua and Barbuda>, <WorldBorder: Algeria>, <WorldBorder: Azerbaijan>, <WorldBorder: Albania>, <WorldBorder: Anguilla>, <WorldBorder: Armenia>, <WorldBorder: Angola>, <WorldBorder: American Samoa>, <WorldBorder: Argentina>, <WorldBorder: Australia>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>`. I updated the question.

Comment: @sk001 I found it :D. I added an edit to my answer that explains and fixes the problem!

Comment: Thank you, @John. It's ok now. Thank you.